# Disable (configure) the jquery-validation for input?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, validation

Sorry for translate. I could not find a solution. Input added to the view manually is not associated with the model. The second input is just for comparison:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...

    <input id="1" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
}
<input id="2" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
```

At startup (on page):

```
<form action="/Calls/Create" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    ...   
    <input id="1" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
</form>
<input id="2" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
```

After typing (on page):

```
<form action="/Calls/Create" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    ...
    <input id="1" class="form-control input-validation-error" 
    type="text" value="" aria-describedby="1-error" aria-
    invalid="true">
</form>
<input id="2" class="form-control" type="text" value="">
```

Jquery adds some attributes for the first input that is in the form block. Second input is unchanged. As far as I understand it's working jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js. If you wrote something other than numbers in the first input, then submit does nor work and puts the cursor there. How to disable this validation or how to configure it? What is the reason for this behavior? Thanks

Comment: you do not want the client side validation at all ? Just do not load that js file then.

Comment: Simply stripping out `script` tag which linked to `jquery.validate.*` or remove all validate script bundles should work.

Comment: Yes, disabling the jquery-script is a radical solution, and it works. But I would like to know how to set it up for each input.

Answer (score 0):

The reason, is when you created this project, you used default MVC template instead of a blank project.
This template contains jquery validation, so if you don't need it, you can remove by:

1. Check on your Views, most of the time, it will under `@Section Scripts`:
   `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`

Remove this line if you just want to remove the jquery validation from that page. **In case you want to take out jquery validation from your whole projects, go to step 2 onward**

2. Locate to `~/App_Start/BundleCongfig.cs`, you will see this:

   ```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
   "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
   ```

It means: create a new Script bundle name "jqueryval" and add all files (javascript file) in Scripts folder, started with `jquery.validate` to this bundle.

That's why, in step 1, any View you need Jquery validation, you just need to call out this "jqueryval" bundle (mentioned in step 1)

Remove this bundle from BundleCongfig.cs file and go to step 3

3. Remove real physical javascript files in `~/Sciprts` folder: `jquery.validate.js` , `jquery.validate.min.js`, `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`, `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js`